# What cartoon had a girl going to another dimension, assisted by a boy with a computer?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I have a vague recollection of some sort of cartoon in which a (pink?) girl is sent on missions in some sort of other dimension.  I remember she has a friend instructing and helping her out; I think it was a boy with some sort of computer.  They had a link between the worlds so that they could communicate.  I remember just one scene, where the girl was sprinting towards the portal away from the dimension, but she was running out of time to escape?..

The cartoon was in English, and probably aired about ten years ago.

I'm so sorry if this is too vague to be answered, but it's been driving me crazy for weeks! Many thanks to anyone who knows what I'm thinking of.

Comment: Roughly when did you watch it? Was it in English? Did it seem to be dubbed?

Comment: It was a long time ago; my best guess it roughly ten years.  It was in English, and when I think of it I think of those really old, original Cartoon Network shows. Does that help at all, or am I going crazy?

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97408/what-tv-show-has-kids-entering-a-video-game-of-some-sort (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 10):

Sounds like it may be ***Code Lyoko***.

From Wikipedia:

> Jeremie Belpois, a profoundly gifted and intelligent thirteen-year old **boy** attending boarding school at the fictional Kadic Academy, one day discovers **a quantum supercomputer** in an abandoned factory near his school. Upon activating it, he discovers **a virtual world** called Lyoko and Aelita, a young **girl** trapped inside it.

The girl, Aelita, has pink hair.

The show first aired in the US on Cartoon Network ten years ago, in 2004.

[image]

Comment: If you add a pic or a vid this answer would go from good to great.

Comment: But Code Lyoko is French, not English. OP might have confused a dubbed version with the original one, though.

Comment: OP probably just meant they originally saw it in English, not necessarily that it was *created* in English.

Comment: Having seen this personally, I can confirm that the dub is *very* good, probably because it was created by the same company that made the original.  Regarding whether this is what OP wants: "I remember just one scene, where the girl was sprinting towards the portal away from the dimension, but she was running out of time to escape?" -> This doesn't ring any bells for me.  Could be a reference to Sector 5's transporter thingy, but this is far from typical for the show.

Answer (score -2):

[The Life and Times of Juniper Lee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Life_and_Times_of_Juniper_Lee)

Comment: Hi there! Could you [edit] in how this matches the description given by the asker?