# 2015ish Netflix cartoon with a group of kids who enter a portal in a computer and find a girl trapped in there

Tags: story-identification, virtual-worlds, animated-series

Okay, so when I was younger I used to watch this animated kids show, this was probably around 2015-19 where a group of kids find this computer, one I'm 90% was in a wheelchair, and all the other kids would be able to go into the portal except for wheelchair kid. The kids found a girl in the program/game and she was trapped there + the kids fought villains with her. While all this is happening, wheelchair kid is observing them through the game. I'm sure this was on either Netflix or Prime Video, which is what my family streamed from at the time. I have been scavenging for this show for so long, and I've come here. Please help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Can you describe the appearance of any of the characters, such as their sex, hair colour, etc? Also, was the animation style 2D or 3D, and can you name any shows with a similar premise which definitely _aren't_ the one you're looking for?

Comment: In which country did you watch this show on Netflix? Some locations don't have the same lineup as others, or may not have had the same lineup at the time you watched it. That said, I'm 99% sure you're talking about a French show called Code Lyoko which was broadcast on Cartoon Network in the USA circa 2004 and which I *think* might've been on US Netflix in your timeframe.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

*[Code Lyoko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Lyoko)* may be a match as per the accepted answer to [What TV show has kids entering a video game of some sort?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/97408/23243).

[image: Title image for Code Lyoko]

> Jeremie Belpois, a gifted thirteen-year-old boy attending boarding school at the fictional Kadic Academy, one day discovers a quantum supercomputer in an abandoned factory near his school. Upon activating it, he discovers a virtual world called Lyoko with a young girl, Aelita, trapped inside it. Unusual events begin to occur at Kadic Academy. Jeremie learns of X.A.N.A., a rogue, malevolent artificial intelligence multi-agent system who also dwells within the supercomputer. X.A.N.A.'s goal is to conquer the real world and all human beings.
>
> Jeremie must materialize Aelita into the real world and stop X.A.N.A. Jeremie is aided by his three best friends and classmates Ulrich Stern, Odd Della Robbia, Yumi Ishiyama as they, along with Aelita, are virtualized into Lyoko in order to save both worlds from the sinister virtual entity.

As noted in that answer, while Jeremie is not in a wheelchair, he also usually stays behind to act as mission control because he's more mentally than physically gifted.

### Opening

And it was indeed on Netflix and Amazon Prime Video.

> All four seasons were made available on Netflix on 6 August 2012, but was removed for unknown reasons. The show was eventually returned to Netflix on 1 October 2020 after being taken down after the bankruptcy of MoonScoop for seven years.[12] Since 2015, all of the English-dubbed episodes (including the prequel XANA Awakens) are currently viewable on YouTube. Since 2019, an upscaled HD version of the series is also available on Amazon Prime Video in the U.S. and the United Kingdom.