Animated show with a group of friends fighting virtual (?) monsters
I'm trying to identify a tv show about a group of friends fighting monsters to stop them from invading the real world.
They all live in a house. I remember there were at least two women and a guy with glasses.
Although it's animated the characters are realistic.
It aired around 2014~2015. I watched it in French, maybe it was on Disney+ or another channel. It was probably a children's cartoon
I have been trying to find it for the past week but to no avail.

Was the animation hand-drawn (2D) or computer-generated (3D)? Also, can you rule out any shows with a similar premise?

If someone posts a correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

This description fits "World Trigger" reasonably well.
The full cast is rather large, but the core group of 5 or 6 live together in a house. The senior member is an older guy with glasses.  The youngest resident of the house has a large pet capybara that he rides around on; that wasn't a big deal in the story but if you remember a capybara, this has got to be it. The leader of the core group of kids also has glasses, but he's one of the younger ones.
They are all members of an organization called Border that uses virtual weaponry to defend the city against invasion through a gate to some other world or dimension that virtual (sort of?) creatures emerge from.
There were 3 seasons of the anime. The English version aired starting in 2014;  there was a French version but I don't know whether it was released at the same time.
Season 1 OP: 



Here is a trailer for the first season, also showing the invading monsters. Defeated monsters "decompose" in pixel-like cubes and disappear, which could explain why the OP thought they were virtual creatures.

Kids fighting virtual monsters and it being in French makes me think of Code Lyoko.


Code Lyoko is a French animated television series created by Thomas Romain and Tania Palumbo. The series centers on four boarding school students, Jeremy (originally Jérémie), Ulrich, Yumi, and Odd, who travel to the virtual world of Lyoko to fight against an evil and sinister sentient artificial intelligence/multi-agent computer program called XANA with a virtual humanoid being named Aelita. The series features both two-dimensional animation and CGI.

Opening




If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97408/what-tv-show-has-kids-entering-a-video-game-of-some-sort
